# Yii framework explanation

Tags: html, css, yii

I have one question about Yii framework, and I need your help.

Basicly, I have php statement which shows user's name.

```
<?php echo Yii::app()->user->name;?>
```

This command will show e.g. "Harry Stamper" somewhere on page.

Imagine this scenario, I have several users, let's choose one, e.g. "John Doe" when I click on his page php statement from above will show "John Doe", as it should.

My question is: How to change this, so if I go to my page, title doesn't show "Harry Stamper" but shows "Your Page" for all members. So member home page becomes "Your Page" instead of your member name.

I think this is done with php if/else and user ID but I'm not sure how to do it in Yii. 
Any help would be awesome.

Comment: I think you are asking something which is bit explained here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9786385/change-the-content-title-of-the-page-in-yii-framework

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your scenario confuses me a little bit, as you are talking about visiting someone else's page and seeing the name of that user using the Yii::app()->user->name. Because this statement is relevant only for logged in user's name and not to be used for showing names of author or owner of pages or articles.

Yii::app()->user is an instance of the CWebUser class which is initialised when the application is run. Yii::app()->user->name will show "Guest" if the user is not logged in, else it shows the username used to login.

You can always use the function Yii::app()->user->setName() to set the full name in the login code.

Thanks

Comment: Ok, let me rephrase. If i go to my page, I have "Harry Stamper" if I'm logged in. I want to change this so it doesn't shows my Name but "Your Page". This should be default setting for all users. So John Doe's page will also become "Your Page" for him etc.

Comment: so the code that show **<name>'s Page** is echo Yii::app()->user->name?? But shouldn't it be **$pageObj->owner** ??