# Change the content title of the page

Tags: php, yii

In Yii framework view page I have the breadcrumb and just below it the content part is there.Now as per my requirment I want the content title should come above the breadcrumb.Now to change the content part and to extract the title of the content I saw that the content part has only this `<?php echo $content; ?>`.

So how to extract the title and place the breadcrumb part below that part?

Answer (score 3):

Layouts! All the explanation on how the breadcrums/title are rendered (after/before the echo $content), is in http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/249/understanding-the-view-rendering-flow/.

In layouts, use
$this->pageTitle for title

and

$this->breadcrumbs for breadcrums

For breadcrums widget, see example:
$this->widget('zii.widgets.CBreadcrumbs', array(
        'links'=>$this->breadcrumbs,)); ?>